# how to print distinct pattern and its count in perl?

Tags: perl

I have to print distinct pattern and its count using Perl, array will be having following inputs :

```
xe-0/0/0
xe-0/0/1
xe-0/0/2
xe-0/0/3
xe-0/1/0
xe-0/1/1
pf-0/0/0
pf-0/0/1
xt-0/1/0
```

output should be:

```
xe-0/0 has 4 interface
xe-0/1 has 2 interface
pf-0/0 has 2 interface
xt-0/1 has 1 interface
```

Comment: Array? What array are you talking about? I don't see any array in your question.

Comment: These are array inputs , for ex. a[0]="xe-0/0/0";

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the input matching on the longest substring before the '/' and maintain a count of occurrences in `%h`. After completely processed, print the counts sorted by value descending.

```
perl -ne '$h{$1}++ if /(.*)\//; END { print "$_ has $h{$_} interface\n" for sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h; }' in
```

or

```
my %h; 
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    ++$h{$1} if m[(.*)/];
}
print "$_ has $h{$_} interface\n" 
   for sort {$h{$b} <=> $h{$a};} keys %h;
```